# How do I connect vocabularies and filter them to be depend on each others?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

The vocabularies I use are:

- TV Channels
- TV Shows

The "TV Channels" vocabulary includes 6 terms, where each term represents a TV Channels (e.g. channel<1>, channel<2>, channel<6>).

The TV Shows vocabulary includes 30 terms, where each term represents a TV Show, but not all of them belong to a one TV Channel, but some of them belongs to channel<1>, and others for channel<2>.

I've already created a content type, and added various fields for these vocabularies using term references.

How do I make a filter? When I choose the TV channel from the filed, and then move to the next filed for the TV Show I should only find the ones belonging to this TV channel, and not the whole TV shows from all the channels.

---

This is a very clever idea, but will it allow me to list all TV Show episodes when I click on any given TV Show link?

Also about the main presenter, how can I add it to the content type the same way?

My point is to find a way to list contents in the website as a whole by:

1. TV channel
2. TV show
3. Main presenter and guest
4. Topic
5. Date of broadcasting

So I've created various taxonomies like the following:

- I created a vocabulary for each one of the above first four items.
- I added terms for each one of them:

  1. TV Channel vocabulary
  2. TV Show vocabulary
  3. Main Presenter & Guest
  4. Topic
- I have installed these modules:

  - Chaos Tool Suite
  - Form Elements - Hierarchical Select
  - Panels
  - Taxonomy Menu
  - Views
- I added a content type with these fields:

  - TV Channel
  - TV Show
  - Main Presenter
  - Guest
  - Topic
  - Broadcasting Date: This one I need to make it in a pop up calender way so if I click on any given date to list all episodes for various TV Shows from any given TV Channel.

The first five fields are term reference fields.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative solution is to add a single vocabulary "TV" and make it two level. In first level all the "channels" will come and "shows" will be added as a child term (second level). Now for reference use "Hierarchical Select" module.